# Separate data in <> with cmd

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

I have a file with the content as in test.txt file. [test.txt](https://anotepad.com/notes/ktp7yrm4)
it includes strings `<string><string><string>.....<string>` lots more.
There is 1 part containing `uid: "text="1000***********"` contains 16 numbers. I need to separate them by command line in windows 10. please help me.this code t used but it not working:

---

```bat
@echo off 
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr "1000" "test.txt"') do set "LINE=%%I" & for /F "delims=zxcvbnm,.asdfghjkl;: /><?\qwertyuiop[]-=``'' " %%J in ('cmd /V /C "echo/!LINE:*1000^=1000!"') do echo %%J>C:\Users\ADMIN\Pictures\Regfb\uid.txt`
```

Comment: The data is one line, 23K characters long. The target string appears to be `<node index="0" text="100084525094698"`. `cmd` limits strings to ~8190 characters and `100084525094698` is 15 characters long, not 16 as claimed, so I believe this cannot be done in batch, but may be possible with a string-processor like `sed` or `(g)awk`.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion between 15 and 16 numbers. Can you help me write the code?

Comment: Why you create files with such huge lines? Just to make much harder to help you? **`:(`** I am pretty sure you could split the file in short lines and it would continue work the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Batch file split your file with a huge line into lines ending in `>`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :SplitFile < test.txt > fields.txt
goto :EOF


:SplitFile

rem Read next chunk
set "chunk="
set /P "chunk="
if not defined chunk goto EndOfFile

rem Split chunk in lines ending in ">"
for %%n in (^"^
%Do NOT remove this line%
^") do set /P "=!chunk:>=>%%~n!" < NUL

goto SplitFile

:EndOfFile
echo/
```

After that, is very easy to process this file with standard Batch commands. For example:

```
for /F "tokens=5 delims== " %a in ('findstr "1000" fields.txt') do @echo %~a
```

Output:

```
100084525094698
```

Comment: Maybe, but first you should acknowledge my effort...

Comment: oh. sorry. tks u.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a regex with powershell and set it into the variable `UID` with `for /f` loop like this :

---

```bat
@echo off
Set "PsCommand=Powershell -C "$regex = [regex]'(\d{15})';$data = GC "test.txt";ForEach ($m in $regex.Matches($data)) {$UID= $m.Value}; $UID""
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%PsCommand%') do Set "UID=%%a"
echo UID=%UID%
echo %UID%>UID.txt
pause
```

Comment: If this another problem just open a new question?  since you have accepted the other answer !

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` (I use GNU sed - Google is your friend)

```
sed s/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/g untitled1.txt >>C:\Users\ADMIN\Pictures\Regfb\uid.txt`
```

should work for you.

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.