# Filter strings within <...> using a Windows 10 script

Tags: string, powershell, batch-file

In the file `testxml.txt`, there are a series of strings enclosed within, and separated by `<` and `>`.

I want to filter in those strings 2 values: `text="any character"` and `bounds="[number][number]"`.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><hierarchy rotation="0"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.facebook.katana" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,2076]"><node index="0" text="Create account" resource-id="com.facebook.katana:id/(name removed)" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.facebook.katana" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[168,108][533,264]" /></node></hierarchy>UI hierchary dumped to: /dev/tty//
```

The expected output is 1 file, `output.txt`, which contains

```
text=""|bounds="[0,0][1080,2076]"
text="Create account"|bounds="[168,108][533,264]"
....
text=""|bounds="[][]"
```

Comment: Sample input and output (in the form of code/markup rather than prose), is always useful. Your question should be self-contained as well, so don't link to external resources unless there's truly no alternative -- put the contents in the question instead (shorten it as necessary).

Comment: Batch isn't the right tool for that (no REGEX, limited variable size). You need (the help of) another language (like in the answer to your last question)

Comment: @JeroenMostert. I have corrected the question. thanks for reminding

Comment: @Stephan. Can you use powershell to handle it?

Comment: OK, so with your input as full XML, it's clear that `cmd` batch files are not the way to go. PowerShell can easily do this as it has full support for XML (`$x = [xml] (Get-Content myfile.xml)`).

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73318726/edit) and add the output expected that can should be in your example ?

Comment: @Hackoo. I have corrected the question, my english is not good so use google translate. The output will be when extracting the elements in each <...> with the format: text="any character"; bounds="[number][number]". save to output.txt file line by line.

Comment: @JeroenMostert . can you help me write the complete command?

Comment: No, because you're still missing desired output based on your input -- and I also doubt the XML you posted is actually representative, as the nesting of `node`s is a bit fishy. `bounds` is easy to extract (`$x.hierarchy.node.bounds`) but what is `text="any character"` in this scenario? XML is not just an arbitrary blob of text, it has actual structure.

Comment: @Hackoo . Sorry I haven't made a clear request. I have re-edited the question and the desired output.

Comment: You could load this as xml, but it looks like it has some mistakes in it.  `[xml]$xml = get-content file.xml; $xml.hierarchy.node | select text,bounds`

Comment: Try to use this https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming file.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
  <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.facebook.katana" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,2076]" />
  <node index="0" text="Create account" resource-id="com.facebook.katana:id/(name removed)" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.facebook.katana" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[168,108][533,264]" />
</hierarchy>
```

Do

```
[xml]$xml = get-content file.xml
$xml.hierarchy.node | select text,bounds

text           bounds
----           ------
               [0,0][1080,2076]
Create account [168,108][533,264]
```

Dumping out every "node" in that other file:

```
Select-Xml //node file2.xml | % node | select text,bounds
```

Comment: [file.xml](https://anotepad.com/notes/dna4tx2s). and your code only returns 1 result

Comment: @vinhnguyen I don't understand the organization of that.

Comment: tks you. it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First, you must process your file with a huge line into shorter lines via the solution posted at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73314411/separate-data-in-with-cmd), that create the `fields.txt`file.

After that, run this Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a "NewLine" value
for %%n in (^"^
%Do NOT remove this line%
^") do (

   rem Process fields.txt file
   (for /F "delims=" %%a in (fields.txt) do (
      set "field=%%a"
      rem Remove closing ">"
      set "field=!field:~0,-1!"
      rem Split field into lines ending in quote-space
      for /F "delims=" %%b in (^"!field:" ="%%~n!^") do echo %%b
   )) > lines.txt

)

rem Process lines
set "data="
for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (lines.txt) do (
   set "tag=%%a"
   if "!tag:~0,5!" equ "<node" (
      rem Start of new node: show data of previous one, if any
      if defined data (
         echo text=!text!^|bounds=!bounds!
      )
      rem Define the data in the same line of "<node"
      set !tag:* =!
      set "data=1"
   ) else if "!tag:~0,6!" equ "</node" (
      rem Show data of last node
         echo text=!text!^|bounds=!bounds!
   ) else (
      rem Define data
      2> NUL set %%a
   )
)
```

Output sample:

```
text=""|bounds="[0,0][1080,2076]"
text=""|bounds="[0,0][1080,2076]"
text=""|bounds="[0,108][1080,2076]"
text=""|bounds="[0,108][1080,2076]"
text=""|bounds="[0,108][1080,276]"
text=""|bounds="[0,108][168,276]"
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't made a clear request. I have re-edited the question and the desired output. file testxml.txt has been minified. The full file will have lots of <><><><><><> strings. Can you help me rewrite the processing code?

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, but you can solve the large single-line problem in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73323261/778560)

Comment: @Stephan: No, because we _first_ create the `fields.txt` file, and _then_ process it...

Comment: @Aacini help me

Comment: @vinhnguyen: Ready. My answer was modified with the new code

Comment: @Aacini ,Tks u. I have tried your code.
- The code that converts 1 large line into many small lines works fine.
- The following processing code gave unexpected results

Answer (score 0):

@Aacini . This is the content of the file lines.txt

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' 
<hierarchy rotation="0
<node index="0
text="
resource-id="
class="android.widget.FrameLayout
package="com.facebook.katana
content-desc="
checkable="false
checked="false
clickable="false
enabled="true
focusable="false
focused="false
scrollable="false
long-clickable="false
password="false
selected="false
bounds="[0,0][1080,2076]
```

Comment: Not here. In my computer all those lines ends in quote, excepting the first one that ends in `?`. I tested this again just now... Check that all _lines_ in `fields.txt` file ends in `>`

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this batch file :

---

```
@echo off
If exist output.txt Del output.txt
Powershell -C "$regex = [regex]'(text=\x22[\s\S]+?\x22)|(bounds=\x22[\s\S]+?\x22)';$data = GC "test.txt";ForEach ($m in $regex.Matches($data)) {$m.Value>>output.txt};"
If exist output.txt Start "" output.txt
```

Comment: The result does not match the requested output format. [output.txt](https://anotepad.com/notes/je3d4ink). You can view the full test.txt file here [test.txt](https://anotepad.com/notes/qq4ewre3)